# Lighthouse score. Does it measure every indexed page?

Tags: performance, pagespeed, lighthouse

How lighthouse measure our page speed? Does it go through all indexed pages from sitemap or does it only cares about homepage?

My use case is that I optimised homepage for over 50 points but other subpages are below 30. Would it affect how google treat my page?

Answer (score 0):

Lighthouse runs a barrage of tests against **the page that you are testing**(It could be homepage, about, product etc.) and then generates a report on how well the page did.